# Best practice for using generics with Firebase snapshot.getValue()

Tags: java, generics, firebase-realtime-database

**TL;DR: How to correctly use a generic class with Firebase DataSnapshot.getValue()?**

Use case: I want to implement a single generic remote datasource class for all my entities (a bunch of them) using Firebase. When listening to data change, I want to get the values from datasnapshot as an object of type E (its type determined elsewhere) but I don't know if it is doable with Firebase query, like the following:

```
public class GenRemoteDataSource<E extends SomeClass>
{
   //...
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
   {
        E item = (E) dataSnapshot.getValue(); // <- unchecked cast and it doesn't work
        items.add(item);
   }
}
```

For example, I have a Foo class that extends SomeClass, and the implementation of this GenRemoteDataSource with a class of Foo would be:

```
public class Foo extends SomeClass{}

public class FooRemoteDataSource extends GenRemoteDataSource<Foo>
{
   //...
}
```

but Firebase throws a runtime error because instead of casting the getValue() as Foo, it would try to cast value as a upper bound SomeClass instead. I'm baffled as to why this happens:

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.example.app.SomeClass
```

please advise on how should I do this with Type-safety (No unchecked cast) . Thank you.

**EDIT** Stuff turned out to be irrelevant down below, see [GenericTypeIndicator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/GenericTypeIndicator)

<strike>**EDIT**
I've also tried (blindly and heck worth a try) the GenericTypeIndicator,</strike>

```
GenericTypeIndicator<E> mTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<>();
E item = dataSnapshot.getValue(mTypeIndicator);
```

but it instead spits the following runtime error.

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Not a direct subclass of GenericTypeIndicator: class java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR my solution, (introduces more dependency than semantically necessary ?)**

```
public class GenRemoteDataSource<E extends SomeClass>
{
   //...
   private final Class<E> clazz;

   GenRemoteDataSource(Class<E> clazz)
   {
      this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   //...
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
   {
        E item = dataSnapshot.getValue(clazz); // <- now is type safe.
        items.add(item);
   }
}
```

I ended up just providing the Class definition to the getValue() via a constructor injection. This is done by passing a `Class<T>` into the generic class's constructor and sets it for Firebase's getValue() to use as a instance parameter. Please comment if there are better solution, because to me this seems redundant. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

My solution in Kotlin for anybody interested:

```
class FirebaseParser<T>(val klass: Class<T>) {

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <reified T : Any> invoke() = FirebaseParser(T::class.java)
    }

    private fun checkType(t: Any): Boolean {
        return when {
            klass.isAssignableFrom(t.javaClass) -> true
            else -> false
        }

    }

    fun convert(data: DataSnapshot): T {

            val res = data.getValue() // Get out whatever is there.
                ?: throw MyCustomExceptionWhichIsHandledElseWhere("Data was null") // If its null throw exception

            if(checkType(res)) {
                return res as T //typecast is now safe
            } else {
                throw MyCustomExceptionWhichIsHandledElseWhere("Data was of wrong type. Expected: " + klass  + " but got: " + res.javaClass) // Data was the wrong type throw exception
            }
    }

}
```

**Examples of instantiation**

Here are some examples of instantiation of the class from java:

```
FirebaseParser<String> firebaseStringParser = new FirebaseParser<>(String.class);
FirebaseParser<Boolean> firebaseBooleanParser = new FirebaseParser<>(Boolean.class);
```

and from kotlin

```
val stringParser: FirebaseParser<String> = FirebaseParser(String::class.java)
val booleanParser: FirebaseParser<Boolean> = FirebaseParser(Boolean::class.javaObjectType) //javaObjectType so we do not compare Boolean to boolean without knowing
```

If doing it this way in Kotlin you need to make sure you not compare a prinmitive type to a class type without knowing