# Use generics in Firebase together with Interfaces, exception is thrown

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an app that is supposed to show a list of agricultural products for sale (beans, potatoes, etc) products are sold in lots so I created the following classes

```
data class LotDto<out T:ProduceDto>(
    val lotId: String = "0",
    val quantity: Int = 0,
    val unitPriceOrigin: Int = 0,
    val unitPriceDestination: Int = 0,
    val destination: String = "ESTELI",
    val seller: UserDataDto = UserDataDto(),
    val dateCreated: String = "never",
    val dateUpdated: String = "never",
    val produce:T = FrijolDto() as T
)
```

and as an example of a produce (frijol means bean)

```
data class FrijolDto(
    val category: String = "Frijol",
    val unitOfMeasurement: String = "qq",
    val variety: String = "Frijol Rojo",
    val humidity: Int = 100,
    val purity: Int = 0,
    val origin:String="Nowhere",
    val harvest: String = "primera",
    val photoPath: String = "",
    val isVerified: Boolean = false,
    val comment: String = "" //agregar curado
):ProduceDto{
 overide fun someMethodCommonToAllProduce(){}
}
```

a PotatoeDto would contain different properties but also extend ProduceDto interface.

the problem is that when I try to cast `dataSnapshot.getValue((GenericTypeIndicator<LotDto<@JvmSuppressWildcards FrijolDto>>(){}))` I get `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.ccy.apps.frijolesonline.data.remote.dto.ProduceDto`. I know that I could simply create different types of Lots to get different types of produce from from the database but that would make my code base balloon out as I add more and more types of produce. Also my compose Activity Is interacting with the different types of produce through the Produce Interface so I would only need to develop the UI once and cover all types of produce at the same time,  however, Firebase is holding me back.

Is there some way to achieve what I am trying to do with firebase?

The only alternative I can think of is adding produce into Lot as a HashMap of properties that can change from produce to produce, but this seems like an ugly hack that makes my code base even less intelligible and opens the door to all kind of inconsistencies.

any ideas are welcome

**Edit as requested**

here the methods contained in my firebaseConection class:

```
private val transactionRef=firebaseDb.getReference("transactions")
private val archiveRef=firebaseDb.getReference("archive")
private val usersRef=firebaseDb.getReference("users")
private val frijolesTransactions=transactionRef.child("frijoles")

suspend fun getFrijolesLots():Resource<HashMap<String,LotDto<FrijolDto>>>{

        return when(val response=frijolesTransactions.getEvent()){

            is Resource.Success -> {
                val ti= object: GenericTypeIndicator<TransactionDto<@JvmSuppressWildcards FrijolDto>>(){}
                val result= HashMap<String,LotDto<FrijolDto>>(response.data!!.children.associate { it.key!! to it.getValue(ti)!!.lot })
                Resource.Success(result)
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                Resource.Error(message = response.message)

            }
            else -> {
                Resource.Error(message = "unexpected error")
            }
        }
    }

suspend fun DatabaseReference.getEvent(): Resource<DataSnapshot> = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        val onSuccessListener =
            OnSuccessListener<DataSnapshot> { snapshot -> continuation.resume(Resource.Success(snapshot)) }
        val onFailureListener = OnFailureListener {continuation.resume(Resource.Error(message = it.message))}
        get().addOnSuccessListener(onSuccessListener).addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener) // Subscribe to the event
    }
```

I should mention that here I am casting the `dataSnapshot` to a `TransactionDto<FrijolDto>` class that basically just passes on the generic (FrijolDto in this case) to `LotDto<T:ProduceDto>` but I dont think this is causing the issue.

I should mention that I already managed to get the data propperly if I hardcode `TransactionDto` and `LotDto` to exclusively take `FrijolDto` instead of a generic `T` The issue only arises due to me adding `T:ProduceDto`

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48237786/10637400) link points to the same fundamental problem but I am not quite sure how to apply the answers to my use case

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to read the data from the Realtime Database and the exact node from where you read that data.

Comment: @Alex I just added some more context I hope It helps you